# Flush CPU caches in C++ by iterating an array and disable compiler optimizations

Tags: c++, caching, benchmarking, compiler-optimization

For benchmarking reasons, I need to run the same algorithm over the same data multiple times. Now, I want to explore the case where all the runs over the same data are on cold caches.

I was thinking of adding a for loop reading every element of an array (LOAD/MOV instruction on every element) so the cache fill with the array elements. Eg.

```
vector<size_t> vec(CACHE_SIZE/sizeof(size_t));
//...
//...
size_t element;
for (size_t i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
    element = vec[i];
}
```

But when compiled with optimization, all of this will probably be removed.

So how do I do this, possibly with minimal overhead.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `element` to be [`volatile`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cv). Accesses and assignments to a volatile variable are not allowed to be optimized away.

```
volatile size_t element;
```

Comment: This makes sense. It should probably generate additional LOAD/MOV to memory instruction but that seems fine. I'll check it out.

Comment: `vector<volatile size_t> vec` might be better, but I'm not sure if this is allowed.